# Question about the motivation of changing the commission rule of Employee Stock Purchase Plan (ESPP)

Tags: espp

I am wondering what might be the cause that company gets rid of the "lookback" provision for stock commission.

Does the company need to pay for the price difference between the commission price and market price or any other big fee is involved? Why would company remove lookback provision or lower the purchase price discount?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what a "lookback option for stock commission" is?

Comment: @DStanley Sorry I used the wrong word. It should be lookback provision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Cost to the company is likely to be the main factor, especially from 2005 onward when rules around ESPPs changed so that offering discounts off the purchase price and providing *lookback provision* became a direct cost to the company.

---

According to [**What is a "lookback"?**](https://www.mystockoptions.com/content/what-is-a-lookback) on the *myStockOptions.com* website, *lookback provision* is a clear win for the employee, as it:

> bases the purchase price not on the stock price at the time of purchase but, rather, on the price either at the beginning of the offering period or at the end of the purchase period, whichever is *lower*.
>   *<sub>Source: https://www.mystockoptions.com/content/what-is-a-lookback</sub>*

From an *employee's* point-of-view, this is a no-brainer: if the stock price has risen over the period, they can buy at the opening price for what amounts to an extra discount; if the price has dropped by the end of the period, they're no worse than if lookback wasn't provided. But what does (did) it cost the *employer* to offer lookback?

According to [**ESPP: What’s In It for the Company?**](https://thefinancebuff.com/espp-what-in-it-for-company.html) on *The Finance Buff* website, prior to 2005, companies were not required to "book an expense" when providing stock options or an ESPP. Therefore, offering an ESPP (with or without *lookback provision*) was beneficial, since:

> Employees got a profit at no cost to the company. If the company paid the employees the equivalent amount in cash, they would’ve had to book an expense and negatively impact their earnings.
>   *<sub>Source: https://thefinancebuff.com/espp-what-in-it-for-company.html</sub>*

So, during this time, since *lookback provision* was essentially always a benefit to the *employee*, and didn't cost the *employer* anything, it made sense to offer it.

However, from 2005 the situation changed:

> The accounting rules changed in December 2004 when the Financial Accounting Standard Board (FASB) issued FAS 123(R). Now companies are required to book an expense for their ESPP unless the discount is no more than 5% and the program doesn’t have a *look-back provision*. As a result, many companies discontinued or scaled back their ESPP plans. Many of them reduced the discount from 15% to 5% and removed the favorable *look-back provision* in order to comply with FAS 123(R) and keep the ESPP off their income statement.
>   <sub>*Source: [ibid](https://thefinancebuff.com/espp-what-in-it-for-company.html)*</sub>

However, the same page also notes that "*for competitive reasons*", some companies would have continued with the schemes "*as is*". From the *employers'* point-of-view, any benefit of offering *lookback provision* are essentially intangible: as the above article says:

> ESPP plans also create employee loyalty. When employees own stocks in the company (if they didn’t sell right away), they are more likely to work harder. In management buzz words, the employees’ interests are “aligned” with the company.
>   <sub>*Source: [ibid](https://thefinancebuff.com/espp-what-in-it-for-company.html)*</sub>

Prior to 2005, they got this "benefit" at no cost; after 2005 they would have to justify the *intangible* benefit against the *tangible* cost involved.

#### Summary

Stopping *lookback provision*, and/or cutting the discount offered under ESPP schemes at the beginning of 2005 would have made financial sense for many companies, as from that date they would incur a new, direct cost.

Any company that *maintained* these benefits past 2005 would need to periodically weigh the intangible benefits (to the *employer*: gained through the *tangible* benefits to the *employees*) of providing ESPPs and *lookback provision* against the (now tangible) cost of doing so.  A company that has *recently* removed its *lookback provision*, and/or reduced the discount offered under its ESPP, may have decided that those *potential* benefits are no longer worth the cost.

Comment: I believe you've written "loopback" multiple times where you meant "lookback"

Comment: @JustinCave Oops... will fix when I'm back on a PC.